# Como puedo colocar una tabla al lado de la otra estando dentro de un while con php

Tags: php, mysql, css, html2pdf

tengo la siguiente consulta:

Imprimo un reporte con la librería html2pdf, php y mysql

Aqui tengo lo que seria el while y este mismo genera el PDF

```
<?php
require ("phpqrcode/qrlib.php");
require("../pdfconex.php");
require("../html2pdf_v4.01/html2pdf.class.php");
$con=conectar();

$pdf=new HTML2PDF("P","Letter","es");

$queryCampostabla="SELECT * FROM recibir_items";
$resulCampostabla=mysqli_query($con,$queryCampostabla);

$dir = 'imagenesQR/';

    
$tabla="<page backtop='28'>
<style>
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    color:#0f0f0f;
}



.imagen1{
    float:left;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.planos{
    float:right;
    display:block;
    margin-left:380px;
    top:538px;
    position: relative;
    width:600px;
    height:80px;
}
.romi{
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
    margin:0 10;
}
.posii{
    width:160px;
    height:65px;
    position:absolute;
    top:45px;
    left:0px;
}

.tabl{
    display:inline-block;
}

        </style>
<page_header>
<h4>REPORTE</h4>
</page_header>
<page_footer>
</page_footer>


";

    

while($row_expo = mysqli_fetch_array($resulCampostabla)){       
        
        $codigoId=$row_expo['id_reci'];
        $codigo=$row_expo['codigo_reci'];
        $descrip_reci=$row_expo['descrip_reci'];
        $ubi=$row_expo['ubi'];
        $est=$row_expo['est'];
        $niv=$row_expo['niv'];
        $ikt=$row_expo['ikt'];
        
        $name        = $codigoId.".png";
        $filename = $dir.$name;
        $tamanio   = 10;  //Tamaño de Pixel
        $level     = 'H'; //Precisión Baja
        $frameSize = 1;  //Tamaño en blanco
        
        QRcode::png($codigoId, $filename, $level, $tamanio, $frameSize);
        

$tabla.="

<div style='float: left; width: 20%;border: 5px solid green;' class='tabl'>
<table border='1' style='font-size:10px;'>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'><b>$descrip_reci</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'><b>$codigo</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style='text-align:center;'><b>$ubi - $est - $niv</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<img src='".$filename."' class='romi'/>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
";
    
}

$tabla.="
</page>";

/*Escribimos nuestro reporte en pdf usando la funcion writeHTML*/
$pdf->writeHTML($tabla);
/*Hacemos la salida del pdf con la funcion Output*/
$pdf->Output("reporte.pdf","L");
?>
```

y todo bien hasta allí, pero por más que use estilos float:left; no funciona nada para que cada tabla salga una al lado de la otra.

De que manera podría hacer esto? colocar por medio de css o html una tabla al lado de la otra sabiendo que estoy imprimiendo la tabla con un while.

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar me seria de gran utilidad.

Saludos.

Comment: Con PHP solo puedes armar código HTML, pero no posicionarlo, eso se hace con CSS. Edita la pregunta y agrega el código como queda en el navegador (`Ver origen de página` o `Ver código fuente de página`)

Comment: Hola @Triby listo ya edite mi pregunta y agregue todo el código que conforma el reporte en PDF

Comment: las 2 tablas se imprimirán en formato de PDF, ¿qué orientación tendrá dicho documento?

Comment: Quiza puedas crearte una tabla con dos columnas y dentro de cada clolumna poner una tabla...